# remote desktop rdp ubuntu 22.04 mouse scroll insensitive to small movements

Tags: mouse, remote-desktop, rdp, mouse-wheel

so I have the following problem: When connecting over the built-in remote desktop rdp feature from ubuntu 22.04, scrolling with the wheel of my mouse is insensitive to small movements: to scroll a normal amount, I have to make a much taller movement with the scroll wheel. Small movements of the mouse wheel are partially not detected at all.

This is specific to the remote desktop rdp (via microsoft remote desktop from another pc):
When using Anydesk to connect to the ubuntu system instead, mouse scrolling works without problems. Other than that, the image quality is great via remote desktop rdp. Lag is not perfect, but ok otherwise too.

Some suggestions?
Thanks!